# scala : create jar from scala files

Tags: scala, jar

I have a bunch of Scala files, java files. The Scala files depend on 1 external Scala jar. Now,   how do I create a jar out of this ?

I am a newbie to Scala. Could you list out step by step procedure for creating the jar ? I am not working with any IDEs and currently working from Linux Terminal

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I use one-jar and sbt-assembly. Both do good job.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'm using one-jar with sbt; so that it includes scala libraries automatically. You need to have one main class for that.

1. Install sbt on your machine http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Setup.html
2. Put all your scala sources to `src/main/scala` and your java files to `src/main/java`
3. Create a folder `project/`
4. Add a file named `plugins.sbt` into it.
5. Somewhere, install the one-jar plugin with the instructions: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-onejar
6. Add the line `addSbtPlugin("org.scala-sbt.plugins" % "sbt-onejar" % "0.8")` to `plugins.sbt` of your main project
7. create a file named `build.sbt` and fill it with the following:

build.sbt:

```
name := "Application name"

version := "1.0" // your version number

organization := "ch.epfl.lara" // your organisation or package name

scalaVersion := "2.10.2" // The scala version used

seq(com.github.retronym.SbtOneJar.oneJarSettings: _*)

libraryDependencies += "commons-lang" % "commons-lang" % "2.6"

mainClass in oneJar := Some("YOUR.PACKAGE.AND.MAINCLASS")
```

Now run `sbt one-jar` in command line in your directory and voilà!